# Distributing large content in Android

Tags: android

I have to distribute large content to be consumed by my application. The data size can be upto a few gbs. What is the best way the data can be sent out?. The solution has to be efficient and cost effective. I ve thought about giving out sd cards (bad solution, since most devices have just one slot and nobody will use it solely for the apps purpose), downloadable from the internet (nobody will download gb's worth data from the internet),package it with the app(Not possible to upload the app to the market)

Comment: You seem convinced that don't want to let them download it, so you're stuck with handing out meatspace objects. I'm not sure why even mention the market, as you've stated you're certain nobody will download the gb's anyway? You can give them sd cards big enough to replace their current ones?

Comment: *"nobody will download gb's worth data from the internet"* - depends. Navigon and other apps do it this way. If your app has enough value for your users, that's not a problem, they will download the content once on a wifi. It will hinder short testing to some degree though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is all of the information needed from the very beginning of the app? Maybe you can incrementally download it in the background and prioritize the data. You can set it so that it only downloads on wifi as well of give an option for it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking can be done. But some of the data I have has to go out in batches of a few gb's. I think optimising internet downloads rather than handing out sd cards seems the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Android market has now extended the maximum APK file size to 4GB.

I would suggest that in the use case of downloading from the internet (i.e on the phone) then you restrict it to wifi only.  THere are plenty examples of this out there using connectionmanager detection.